# Finding the first empty input

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
</div>
```

I have only these inputs on a page and I'm trying to focus and enter a value dynamically into each empty input:

```
document.querySelector('input[value=""]').value = 1
```

... works but only for the first input, shouldn't this select the next empty input everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
document.getElementById('fill').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  document.querySelector('input[value=""]').setAttribute('value', '1');
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
</div>
<button id="fill">Fill</button>
```

`.value = ...` is not actually changing the attribute itself in the DOM. Use `.setAttribute` to make the actual change in the DOM that `querySelector` can see.

Comment: Aah, that was it. Thanks! :)